# How to deal with background jobs and power management

Tags: power-management

On Linux/Unix systems I have in the past been used to putting jobs that take a long time "into the background" and letting them chug away.  However I have found that this seems not work (any more?).  Background jobs simply do not progress unless I am doing "something else" to keep the computer "awake".

I have looked at System -> Control Centre -> Power Management, and I see an option "Put computer to sleep when inactive for:  Never".

Is this the option that I should choose so that background jobs continue to run to completion?  I would have *thought* that if there is a background job running then the computer is *not* "inactive".  Is this not the case?

Will choosing the "Never" option have the desired effect?  What are the unwanted side effects or drawbacks to choosing this option?

Comment: It is completely unrelated.

Comment: This is one of the least helpful answers I have ever seen,  What is unrelated to what?

Comment: This was not an answer, but a comment. That setting doesn't affect background processes. But there is a risk that the computer will go to suspend if you don't press keys or move a mouse for some time. So the setting may be reasonable.